# ¿Cómo agregar costos de envío en WooCommerce según el rol del usuario?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de agregar el envío según el rol del usuario.

¿Cómo gestionar los gastos de envío a partir del precio total sin impuestos?

Hay un tipo de usuario mayorista (wholesale_customer)y luego están el resto de los roles de usuario (Llamémoslos **"El Resto"** ) que tienen las mismas reglas para todos.

Las reglas son las siguientes para usuarios **Mayoristas**: El envío es gratuito si alcanzan la cantidad de 70€ , si no llegan a esa cantidad, los gastos de envío serían 10€, que se suman al total

Las normas para "El Resto" es que el envío es gratuito si superan la cantidad de 30 € , si no se supera esta cantidad, los gastos de envío serían 10 €

Obtengo esto comprobando el rol de usuario con current_user_can()

Para los usuarios que no son Mayoristas, (**"El Resto"**) , todo funciona bien con la siguiente función, ya que el precio de los productos para este tipo de usuario no lleva impuestos.
Funciones:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_costs_for_retailers', 10, 2);
function shipping_costs_for_retailers($rates, $package) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (!in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 30) {
        $new_rate = array();
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            $new_rate[$rate_id] = $rate;
            $new_rate[$rate_id]->cost += 5;
        }
        return $new_rate;
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_shipping_html', 'message_for_retailers');
function message_for_retailers($html) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (!in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 30) {
        $html .= '<p>Shipping cost: $5.00</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

El problema viene con los usuarios con el rol de **mayoristas**, ya que al precio de los productos se le suma un impuesto. Entonces, hay un pequeño margen que me da error. Por ejemplo, si el importe es de 68,40 € , se desactivan los gastos de envío, ya que al añadir los impuestos, el importe total supera los 70 € , que es el importe límite de envío gratuito para estos usuarios. En otras palabras, necesito que este cálculo se haga en base al `subtotal` sin agregar impuestos.

Para este tipo de usuarios he utilizado el mismo sistema que para **"El Resto"** de usuarios, solo he intentado modificar la variable `WC( )->cart->subtotal`, pero no se como hacerlo, realmente he buscado ideas y soluciones, pero No puedo encontrar el camino. Esta es la forma en que trato de administrar los costos de envío en los usuarios **mayoristas**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_ expenses_ for_wholesalers', 10, 2);
function shipping_ expenses_ for_wholesalers($rates, $package) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 70) {
        $new_rate = array();
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            $new_rate[$rate_id] = $rate;
            $new_rate[$rate_id]->cost += 10;
        }
        return $new_rate;
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_shipping_html', 'message_for_wholesalers');
function message_for_wholesalers($html) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 70) {
        $html .= '<p>Shipping cost: $10.00</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

¿Qué debo hacer para corregir esto?

¿Cómo debo modificar mi función para administrar el precio sin el impuesto?

Podéis ver una captura de pantalla de lo que me pasa, cuando un cliente `mayorista`, en el SubTotal no llega a 70€, pero la tarifa de envío está desactivada ya que el total supera los 70€

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias